# Java SHA256 hash not the same as in vb.net

Tags: java, vb.net, hash

I have problems with calculating hash in vb.net.

Working code in Java which calculates good hash is

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String test = "line1\nline2";
        System.out.println(test);
        String testOut = getTest(test);
        System.out.println(testOut);
} 

public static String getTest(String input) {
try {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    md.update(input.getBytes());
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(md.digest());
    } 
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}      
}
```

Output of this code is

```
line1
line2
aDN24pCCm0gsJlV0XK/6eh3M+hCvqmLawrQt1saND4M=
```

Not working example in vb.net is below

```
Dim test As String = "line1\nline2"
Console.WriteLine(test)
Dim mySHA256 As SHA256 = SHA256Managed.Create()
mySHA256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test))
Dim out = Convert.ToBase64String(mySHA256.Hash)
Console.WriteLine(out)
```

Output is below

```
line1\nline2
RrUKDuWDeHhbuSYAZlamp7dr3ujXi3v9cm8xvOUtdM0=
```

So I figured out that "\n" is not a new line for character in vb.net. So i used `vbNewLine`

```
Dim test2 As String = "line1" + vbNewLine + "line2"
Console.WriteLine(test2)
Dim mySHA256_2 As SHA256 = SHA256Managed.Create()
mySHA256_2.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test2))
Dim out2 = Convert.ToBase64String(mySHA256_2.Hash)
Console.WriteLine(out2)
```

Output is below

```
line1
line2
0UqRptHG7oO/DHdOvsvubYs5OzldrinuqDnDVNb7qcA=
```

I tried to use `TransformFinalBlock` instead of `ComputeHash`

```
Dim test3 As String = "line1" + vbNewLine + "line2"
Console.WriteLine(test3)
Dim mySHA256_3 As SHA256 = SHA256Managed.Create()
mySHA256_3.TransformFinalBlock(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test3), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test3).Length)
Dim out3 = Convert.ToBase64String(mySHA256_3.Hash)
Console.WriteLine(out3)
```

and the output is the same as previous

```
line1
line2
0UqRptHG7oO/DHdOvsvubYs5OzldrinuqDnDVNb7qcA=
```

I suspect that Java's newline `"\n"` is causing problems because it calculates wrong hash. If i have string without `"\n"` then the values are the same. In vb.net i tried to use `Environment.NewLine` instead of `vbNewLine` and same result

Comment: The equivalent of `\n` in VB is `vbLF`.  `Environment.NewLine` and `vbNewLine` are platform dependent, but in windows they are equivalent to `vbCR & vbLF`.

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks for a quick response. I was stuck for days to realize that because of new line my hash values are not the same. You can post your comment as answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, if the data that you are encoding does not contain a `\n`, then it works fine.  So you're problem obviously has nothing to do with the hashing algorithm.  You're problem is that you aren't translating the `\n` in your string literal into VB properly so the two input strings are different.  If you output the bytes you would see that the Java one has `0x0A` (10 in decimal) and the VB one has `0x0D 0x0A` (13, 10 in decimal) for the new line.

In VB, `vbCR` is the constant for `\r` (`0x0D`) and `vbLF` is the constant for `\n` (`0x0A`).  `Environment.NewLine` and `vbNewLine` are platform dependent, but in windows they are equivalent to `vbCR & vbLF`.